# Nodemailer SES Throttling error even after defining the ratelimit?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, nodemailer

I faced throttling error even after defining the rate limit in transporter object. Where am I lacking?

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer'); 
const ses = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(ses({
    accessKeyId: "sesKeys_pub",
    secretAccessKey: "sesKeys_pvt",
    region : 'us-west-2',
    rateLimit: 5
}));
transporter.sendMail({
    from: "abc@xyz.com",
    to: "abc@xyz.com",
    subject: "sample",
    html: "<p>html</p>"
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look here? https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/

Comment: transporter.isIdle() always stays false for me so not even a single email is sent. Don't know how that will handle thousands of emails.

Comment: But what error are you getting in `sendMail()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code, `sendingRate` should be used

Documentation: https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/#example-2

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
SES: new aws.SES({
    accessKeyId: "sesKeys_pub",
    secretAccessKey: "sesKeys_pvt",
    region : 'us-west-2',
  }),
    sendingRate: 5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the sendingRate and then use sendMail as normal.

```
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: { ses, aws },
  sendingRate: 14,
});

const params = {
  from: 'EMAIL',
  to: 'EMAIL',
  subject: 'Message',
  html: 'I hope this <b>message</b> gets sent!',
  text: 'I hope this message gets sent!',
  // attachments: [{ filename: 'card.pdf', content: data, contentType: 'application/pdf' }],
};

transporter.sendMail(params, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
  console.log(info.envelope);
  console.log(info.messageId);
});
```

Important thing to note here, nodemailer waits for the next second to continue with the next batch of throttled emails and the next and so on. So if you are running a script that exits immediately after calling the last sendMail(), the throttled emails will never get sent. Make sure the process runs until all emails are sent by listening to on idle or use settimeout.